# How to apply the styles for downloadable file

Tags: javascript, .net, css

I have a grid and a button in my application. When we click on the button, the grid is exported(.xls). But my problem is, in the exported file data is not aligned.So I want to apply some style like alignment:left.  How to apply styles for that file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? And try to format your question a bit better, so others can understand you more easily.

Comment: Ya sure I have one grid in my application,when we click on the button then grid is exported(.xls) but in exported file all the data has no alignment.So I want to apply style like alignment:left.

Comment: what are you using to generate the downloadable file (javascript?) ... please post the relevant code ... and we might be able to help. As the file gets generated before downloading ... the style needs to be applied in the same process.

Comment: here is the fiddle what i am trying http://jsfiddle.net/bpdLu/